# Netbeans PHP, how to make autocomplete work from an included file (the classes are declared in the parent)

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

here is the file structure for my question:

test1.php

```
<?php
class Test1 {
    public function testMethod () {
        echo 'test1';
    }
}
```

test2.php

```
<?php
include('test1.php');
$test1 = new Test1();
include('test3.php');
```

test3.php

```
<?php
$test1-> //this is where I'd like the autocomplete to work.
```

So, my question is how to make the autocomplete work in the test3.php file for classes declared in parents files.

I know about the PHPDoc comment trick:

test3.php

```
<?php
/* @var $test1 Test1 */
$test1-> //Now the autocomplete works.
```

In this case it could work, but in a case where there is a lot of classes and a lot of files like test3.php, It's not viable to have 15 comment lines at the begining of 30 files and what  would happens if I add a class later.

If it's impossible, is there a way to enable autocomplete for everything (even undeclared)?

Or would there be a better way to structure my code to make it work with the autocomplete?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way I know of is the variable doc format. I am not aware of anything else, I would love to know if there is another solution, too.

Comment: Feels like a very fragile way to structure your code. Do not use global variables and certainly don't rely on them to be defined by a file that is doing the including.

Comment: @Eelke: I agree, it's not a good way to do it, but sometimes you need a global utility class.

Comment: My file structure is like this because I have an index.php page that is including another page depending on the url, ex: http://website.com/home would check in the database to which page "home" is linked and will include the apropriate one. index.php has all includes (class definitions) I need for the other pages (like in "home").

Answer (score 1):

I met the same question. Seems netbeans doesn't handle the autocomplete in recursive way.I Hope Sun will change it in next release. Eclipse Helios can meet the demand and it's also free, if you don't mind changing your IDE.
For now I'm using phpDesigner, most of it's functions are only so so, but the autocomplete is extraordinarily greate.